# Show $p \lor (p \land q ) \equiv p $ using equivalences

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

## I am trying to show $p \lor (p \land q ) \equiv p $ using equivalences.

I have tried many replacements (e.g. distributivity and de Morgans) but cannot see a way to simplify the left hand side that reduces to $p$.

Here are is a list of logical equivalences from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

I know that this statement is true (via truth tables), but I cannot derive this using equivalences. Ideas appreciated.

Comment: Law of absorption. This is an axiom in lattice theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the list ... but some texts like to derive it as follows:

$$p \lor (p \land q) \equiv (p \land \top) \lor (p \land q) \equiv p \land (\top \lor q) \equiv p \land \top \equiv p$$

Comment: @RobArthan That's an instance of Distribution ... which is often not derived from other equivalence principles. That is, Distribution is often a given equivalence principle.

Comment: @RobArthan By Distribution I mean $p \land (q \lor r) \equiv (p \land q) \lor (p \land r)$

Comment: @RobArthan Why not?  $p=p$, $q= \top$, and $r=q$ ...

Comment: RIght - my brain was not in gear!

Comment: @RobArthan No worries!  It was probably because it went in the 'opposite' direction of what you normally understand 'Distribution' to be ... more like a 'Reverse Distribution' or 'Un-Distribution' or 'Factoring'

Answer (score 4):

This is listed, verbatim, as one of the **absorbtion laws** in the wikipedia page you linked.